# Xcode showing app build settings and CoreData only as Text File

Tags: xcode

Something happened to my Xcode and all settings/Core Data is only shown as Text Code, but not as a menu. How can I change this to the "normal" view?

[image: Example]

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Solved by disabling "Code Review View".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).